# crash reporting with crittercism in react-native project

Tags: react-native, crittercism

I want to use crittercism for "crash reporting/exception handling" in react-native project, Want to check if anyone already has done it ? If yes please guide.

Answer (score 0):

This is Kunal from Apteligent. Unfortunately we do not support React native apps with our sdk yet, although there is a feature request in place and our team is working on it.

Once we have the compatible sdk we will update on our release notes page - https://docs.apteligent.com/release_notes/release_notes.html

Let me know in case of other questions.

Comment: is this feature implemented yet?